# Entity Framework adding multiple record objects to a dbset - can I re-add the same record object?

Tags: entity-framework-6

Using EF Core in a utility processing serial data to insert into a DbSet.

The easiest way to prepare the data is to map it into a row object, and then finally .Add() that object to the DbSet.

But then I need to process more data and add another row. Can I reuse the same object, and .Add() it again, or is the object treated like a reference so that it always points to the same row in the DbSet? In that case what is the best way to serially add multiple rows in an iterative process?

Here is an encapsulation of the code (all in same namespace):

```
[define public class "Person"]

// define DbContext and add Person
public partial class AppDBContext : DbContext
public virtual DbSet<Person> Persons

// program object:
public class MainProgram();
// High-level properties include instance of Person
Person person;

// Data parsing method
public void Process();
while (process to do)
{
  person = new Person();
// Set properties here...
  db.Persons.Add(person);
}
db.Persons.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: can you show your code ?

Comment: Why not use a List<Person> and AddRange?

Comment: I considered that after the fact.
I like working with the Person object while I'm assigning properties.
So I assume you're suggesting that I follow the above process, only .Add(ing) person to the List first, and then when all data is written in .AddRang(ing) the list to the DbContext and then saving?

Comment: ...okay, so while I'm waiting for your answer I'll expand on my answer-question above...

Comment: It sounds like you're implying that manipulating data inside a DbContext.DbSet is inefficient or awkward and therefore it is more practical to use an intermediary List and then AddRange? I'm inclined to think of DbContext as a collection of DbSets but increasingly it seems more like a collection of references / metadata not well suited for heavy processing?
And just to clarify my original question - is that concept of recycling an object instance and re-adding to the DbSet not workable?